# How can I recursively find all files and display the full path and line number using cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

How can I recursively find all files ends with `*.html` ,`*.*.html` (in any form) and get the output of **fullpath of the file** and how many line numbers they have in the `cmd/cmder` (windows)?

I try to do it:

```
     dir *.html /s | wc -l
```

But I got only a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available. This can be put into a .bat file script and run with cmd.exe.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt |" ^
    "ForEach-Object { """$($_.FullName),$((Get-Content $_.FullName ^| Measure-Object).Count)""" }"
```

This produces the filename and line count suitable for saving as a .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to count the line numbers for each file separately (`find /c` can do that quite efficiently):

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.html) do (
  <nul set /p ".=%%a  lines: "
  type "%%a" | find /c /v ""
)
```

Where `for /r` recursively processes each matching file.